# Roboto font not working with Openbox GTK3 applications while other fonts do

Tags: fonts, openbox, gtk3, gtk2, ttf

I am using Debian Stretch with Openbox window manager and I am trying to set the uniform look for GTK2, GTK3, QT4, QT5 widgets. Everything went smoothly except for GTK3 that partially ignores `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` file which looks like this *(I used Lxappearance to modify it)*:

```
gtk-theme-name=Breeze
gtk-icon-theme-name=breeze
gtk-font-name=Roboto Medium 10
gtk-cursor-theme-name=breeze_cursors
gtk-cursor-theme-size=0
gtk-toolbar-style=GTK_TOOLBAR_BOTH_HORIZ
gtk-toolbar-icon-size=GTK_ICON_SIZE_SMALL_TOOLBAR
gtk-button-images=0
gtk-menu-images=1
gtk-enable-event-sounds=0
gtk-enable-input-feedback-sounds=0
gtk-xft-antialias=1
gtk-xft-hinting=1
gtk-xft-hintstyle=hintfull
gtk-xft-rgba=rgb
```

Option `gtk-font-name=Roboto Medium 10` is completely ignored by all GTK3 applications which continue to use their default font `Sans 10` while option `gtk-font-name=Monospace 10` works. Other options like `gtk-button-images=0` also work if I change them and restart GTK3 applications.

So what can I do to be able to use Roboto font in GTK3 applications inside my Openbox window manager?

Roboto font works for GTK2 applications in `~/.gtkrc-2.0`. It looks like `gtk-font-name="Roboto Medium 10"` *(mind the quotes which should be avoided in GTK3 configuration file)*. Roboto font also works for QT4 and QT5 applications and was applied using qt5ct...

So only GTK3 is making problems for Roboto fonts...

Comment: I tried converting Roboto font from ttf font to otf and it works now... I deleted it now. It was exclusively for testing purposes. Still reason why Roboto font doesn't work in ttf format remains unknown...

Comment: Have you tried omitting the Medium part and leave just Roboto 10?

Comment: Yes. Nothing changes.